Automatic build on Jenkins initiated from GitHub. Not working. 502 returned
I am new to Jenkins but have successfully created a Pipeline that will build our project hosted on GitHub.  The user can even specify the branch (master, develop, test, etc.) that they want to build.
Now, I would like to implement automatic builds whenever there is a push to a certain branch (develop for example).  Pushes to other branches should not result in an automatic build.  I am having trouble getting this going and even finding information on it.  I have found:
https://www.devopsschool.com/blog/how-to-build-when-a-change-is-pushed-to-github-in-jenkins/
My first question is:   Are there any other sources of information for setting up automatic builds in Jenkins when the backing source repository is GitHub (as opposed to Bitbucket for example)?. The above mention article is from 2021.  Some of the steps and screenshots do not correspond to recent versions of Jenkins.
Specifically with the article mentioned, I have completed all the steps.  Probably not successfully or things would be working!  Of note in Step 2 I have added GitHub Server. I filled in API URL as https://api.github.com.  Hitting 'Test Connection' results in:
Credentials verified for user davidrunner, rate limit: 4998

which seems like a good sign. I did not click 'Manage hooks' checkbox as document did not seem to check it. I believe I followed step 3 and configured step 4 on the GitHub repository.
However, when I commit and push a test change to either the branch 'master' or 'develop' I see under 'Recent Deliveries' for Webhooks a Red triangle with exclamation mark. The response is empty with '502'.  I believe this means the connection was rejected by the Jenkins machine.
My next questions are: How can I troubleshoot this? What should I check?  I stress again that I can certainly pull the code from Jenkins and build. So, clearly communications between GitHub and Jenkins machine is possible.
Update
I tried the suggestion of Iterokun @Iterokun in the comments below.
When I directly use: 1xx.xx.xxx.xx:8080/github-webhook I see the following errors in Jenkins logs:
May 22, 2024 3:39:06 PM INFO org.jenkinsci.plugins.github_branch_source.ApiRateLimitChecker$RateLimitCheckerAdapter checkRateLimit
LocalChecker for rate limit was not set for this thread. Configured using system settings with API URL 'https://api.github.com'.
May 22, 2024 3:41:21 PM SEVERE org.jenkinsci.plugins.github.webhook.GHEventPayload$PayloadHandler parse
**Unknown content type null**
May 22, 2024 3:41:21 PM WARNING hudson.init.impl.InstallUncaughtExceptionHandler handleException
Caught unhandled exception with ID 288b80b3-2bbf-49ee-a010-c0d2bab5e8d4
**java.lang.Exception: Method POST required**
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.HttpResponses.error(HttpResponses.java:92)

I also tried a curl Post command and got the following:
PS C:\andrew\Firmware> curl.exe -X POST http://1xx.xx.xxx.xx:8080/github-webhook/
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>**Error 400 Hook should contain event type**</title>
</head>
<body><h2>**HTTP ERROR 400 Hook should contain event type**</h2>
<table>
<tr><th>URI:</th><td>/github-webhook/</td></tr>
<tr><th>STATUS:</th><td>400</td></tr>
<tr><th>MESSAGE:</th><td>Hook should contain event type</td></tr>
<tr><th>SERVLET:</th><td>Stapler</td></tr>
</table>
<hr/><a href="https://eclipse.org/jetty">Powered by Jetty:// 10.0.20</a><hr/>

On the Jenkins log, I see:

May 22, 2024 7:26:07 PM SEVERE org.jenkinsci.plugins.github.webhook.GHEventPayload$PayloadHandler parse
Unknown content type null


Whatever webhook url you configured in GitHub, what happens when you hit it directly from your browser? 502 or something else? What do you see in Jenkins logs?

When I use http://1xx.xx.xxx.xx:8080/github-webhook/ I get to the Jenkins page but there is a message that says "Oops! A problem occurred while processing your request  Logging ID=9ab9f0ea-0cb1-4281-b234-ac1a45d34e45
I'll have to figure out where the Jenkins logs are and how I read them!

@Iterokun  I report on what was in the logs after trying your suggestion at the end of my question (as an UPDATE) .  Thanks!

Sorry, my bad, failed to mention you need to do a POST. GitHub uses it for webhooks to deliver payloads. Try with curl -X POST url. Does it change the error message?

Hmm. I'm not super familiar with curl. When I do curl -X POST http://1xx.xx.xxx.xx:8080/github-webhook/   I get:  Invoke-WebRequest : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'X'.
This is on a Command Prompt in Windows

@Iterokun I got Post working with curl.exe -X POST url.   Results are added to Update.  Notice errors on both sides.

I suspect it's okay to get that error message as we don't send over event type info in that simple POST! So, I seem to be able to hit the Jenkins machine based on your test.

It is suspicious that you get 400 locally and 502 from GitHub. Are you sure you are using publicly routable IP for your Jenkins?

I agree! Very strange. I put the problem aside for a while and came back to it. Same results. I can hit the Jenkins machine from anywhere with the "curl" statement.  I do get a "Error 400 Hook should contain event type" message. With Github though, the Response shows as '502'.  I double and triple checked the IP address and spelling of github-webhook.  I tried the Content type as "application/x-www-form-urlencorded" and tried "application/json" !

The only time I get 502 is when there is no network connectivity between GitHub and Jenkins. The best way to test is from your laptop tethered to the cell phone. This way you are off the corp network.

Any chance you can update the question with the last deliveries/payload that was send by the github over the webhook? That may help figure out if there a plugin version mismatch. Another thing could be the size of the payload might have exceeded 20MB causing a bad gateway? Though i think that is unlikely to occur but an easy thing to rule out.

@Iterokun , can you please post some of your comments (especially about curl) in an answer and I'll accept?  You put quite a bit of work into answering this and your comments led to the answer which I'll post.  I can't award the bounty to myself however so I think it's right you should get it.  Details in my answer.

The first thing to try is firing a post request from your laptop to the url you configured in the webhook.
curl -X POST url

You will not get 200, since you are not supplying the expected payload, but it shouldn't be 502 either.
Once you confirm that Jenkins itself is not the source of 502 you can check the network connectivity from outside your network, like from a laptop tethered to your cell phone.
If you discover that it's your network configuration that is blocking the calls you can try opening traffic for the IPs that the webhook calls come from. Those are documented in the meta API endpoint under "hooks".

Thank you @Iterokun !  For future readers, see my answer.  Iterokun's initial comments led me to answer!

I must bashfully admit that the answer was pretty obvious.  Of course, everything is obvious in hindsight :)  Iterokun's comments led to the answer.
My Jenkins instance is behind a firewall and must be accessed via VPN.  That is why I could reach it with @Iterokun 's suggestion of "curl ...". from my work laptop. I'm almost always on VPN. In fact, when I disconnected VPN, I couldn't even ping the Jenkins instance, nevermind using curl.
The github is in the cloud and has no idea about our firewall or VPN.  It can be reached from Jenkins, but it can't reach Jenkins.
So, insead of using Webhooks going from Github to Jenkins, I can poll from Jenkins to Github, or if I'm really bound and determined to get webhooks working there are a few alternatives:

Put Jenkins on Amazon cloud or similar.
Use a commercial relay service (example: https:webhookrelay.com) or roll my own.
I'll post separate questions if I decide to do either 1 or 2. They are also both management decisions above my paygrade :).  For now, I think I'll go with polling from Jenkins to Github. Hopefully that's easy - I've never done it before. Jenkins is all new to me.

